# Namespaces - __autoload() is requiring a wrong class

Tags: php, autoload

I am builded a new object in my file without namespaces:

```
new My\Validator();
```

Above, in the same file I have got `__autoload():`

```
function __autoload($className) 
{
    var_dump($className);
}
```

The `__autoload()` function prints

```
'My\My\Validator'.
```

Where is the double `'My'` come from?

Comment: You need to declare your autoload in global space

Comment: Because of the namespace 'My'?

Comment: Are you calling `new My\Validator();` from the global namespace or the `My` namespace? You may want to look at the `spl_autoload_register` function too - it is more flexible than the `__autoload` function, as it allows you to register multiple autoloaders.

Comment: "in my file without namespaces", that would be global namespace

Comment: @Szymon it doesn't print that for me, it prints "My\Validator", which is expected. Maybe you could provide runnable example where this behaviour occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is adding the `My` namespace because you are probably inside the `My` namespace already when you create the object with `new My\Validator()`.

```
namespace My;
$obj = new My\Validator();
```

will be translated to:

```
$obj = new My\My\Validator();
```

Since you are inside the `My` namespace already you can:

- either just call `new Validator()`
- or call `new \My\Validator()`

The beginning `\` will tell PHP to look into the global namespace.

---

On a side note, it is considere good practice to use [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) instead of `__autoload`, because you can set multiple *autoloader callbacks*.